# Oracle PL/SQL Script vs SQL in SQL Developer ( Invalid Alter Option)

Tags: plsql

I am in the process of trying to create multiple PL/SQL Scripts to help maintain our existing databases and allow us to make modifications to them.  The first one I'm working on is shown below:

```sql
BEGIN
    -- add the field to the table that will be used to check against when 
    -- looking for records that need to be processed.
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(' 
        ALTER TABLE TBL_SAP_VENDORS_COPY 
            ADD UPT_TS TIMESTAMP ;
    ');       
    -- The automatic update of fields has to be performed using a trigger 
    -- First we drop the trigger incase it already exists
    Execute Immediate ('
        drop trigger vendors_updt_mark;
    ');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('
        -- Then add the trigger deffinition
        CREATE TRIGGER vendors_updt_mark
        before  insert or update
            on TBL_SAP_VENDORS_COPY
            FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            :new.UPT_TS := SYSTIMESTAMP;
        END;
    ');
END;
```

I'm having problems with the very 1st statement which is the alter statement:

```
ALTER TABLE TBL_SAP_VENDORS_COPY 
    ADD UPT_TS TIMESTAMP ;
```

When I execute it using the 'Run Script' option in Oracle SQL Developer I get the following error:

```sql
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
BEGIN
    -- add the field to the table that will be used to check against when 
    -- looking for records that need to be processed.
    EXECUTE  (' 
        ALTER TABLE TBL_SAP_VENDORS_COPY 
            ADD UPT_TS TIMESTAMP ;
    ');       
    -- The automatic update of fields has to be performed using a trigger 
    -- First we drop the trigger incase it already exists
    Execute Immediate ('
        drop trigger vendors_updt_mark;
    ');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('
        -- Then add the trigger deffinition
        CREATE TRIGGER vendors_updt_mark
        before  insert or update
            on TBL_SAP_VENDORS_COPY
            FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            :new.UPT_TS := SYSTIMESTAMP;
        END;
    ');
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PLS-00201: identifier 'EXECUTE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
BEGIN
    -- add the field to the table that will be used to check against when 
    -- looking for records that need to be processed.
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(' 
        ALTER TABLE TBL_SAP_VENDORS_COPY 
            ADD UPT_TS TIMESTAMP ;
    ');       
    -- The automatic update of fields has to be performed using a trigger 
    -- First we drop the trigger incase it already exists
    Execute Immediate ('
        drop trigger vendors_updt_mark;
    ');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('
        -- Then add the trigger deffinition
        CREATE TRIGGER vendors_updt_mark
        before  insert or update
            on TBL_SAP_VENDORS_COPY
            FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            :new.UPT_TS := SYSTIMESTAMP;
        END;
    ');
END;
Error report -
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
ORA-06512: at line 4
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

When is execute the same statement by itself in SQL Developer is executes with not problem.'

Comment: Rather than dropping and recreating the trigger, why not do "CREATE AND REPLACE TRIGGER vendors_updt_mark ..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

- [brackets around the column definition](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#i2183462);
- to remove the trailing semi-colon in the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` strings when you are executing an SQL command (however, it is required for PL/SQL blocks); and
- to catch the exception if the trigger does not exist when you try to drop it.

Like this:

```sql
BEGIN
    -- add the field to the table that will be used to check against when 
    -- looking for records that need to be processed.
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('ALTER TABLE TBL_SAP_VENDORS_COPY ADD ( UPT_TS TIMESTAMP )');

    -- The automatic update of fields has to be performed using a trigger 
    -- First we drop the trigger incase it already exists
    DECLARE
      trigger_not_found EXCEPTION;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( trigger_not_found, -4080 );
    BEGIN
      Execute Immediate ('drop trigger vendors_updt_mark');
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN trigger_not_found THEN
        NULL;
    END;

    -- Then add the trigger deffinition
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('
        CREATE TRIGGER vendors_updt_mark
        before  insert or update
            on TBL_SAP_VENDORS_COPY
            FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            :new.UPT_TS := SYSTIMESTAMP;
        END;
    ');
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aa182e17896815e107f1833377bb8eed)*